# Dynamic AD group membership for computers

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to write a script i can run to dynamically manage computers in a security group in AD. I've successfully done the first bit but would like it make some additions. So far I have:
`$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Searchbase "OU=Clients,OU=Devices,DC=domain,DC=local" | select-object -expandproperty DistinguishedName | out-file C:\computers.txt
Get-Content c:\computers.txt | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf 'Group_C'`

I would like to exclude machines that already bellong to Group_A and Group_B and remove machines from Group C if they no longer appear in computers.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will exclude computers from Group_A and Group_B:

```
$GroupA_DN = "<GroupA DistinguishedName>"
$GroupB_DN = "<GroupB DistinguishedName>"

Get-ADComputer -filter {memberof -ne $GroupA_DN -and memberof -ne $GroupB_DN}
```

The `$GroupA_DN` variable will need to have a string of the distinguished name of group A. For example, `$GroupA_DN = "CN=Group_A,OU=SomeOU,OU=Clients,OU=Devices,DC=domain,DC=local"`. The same will need to be repeated for group B in its respective variable.